# R Forecasting Package and Daily Timeseries

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have been using the Forecast Package in R but have found it difficult to load my own daily time series into a ts object and then use this with the forecasting algorithms. I have instead used zoo to create my daily timeseries object, but I can not pass this directly to forecasting algorithms in the R Forecast package.

Any help in the correct direction would be much appreciated. I feel very stuck with this.

Thanks

---

Hi Here is some sample code. With a simple quarterly dataset, I can get some prediction working but with a daily dataset I can't get it working. Many Thanks

```
require("forecast")
require("fpp")

# Example from Forecasting Principles and Practice
# http://otexts.com/fpp/2/5/

#beer2 <- window(ausbeer,start=1992,end=2006-.1)

#start with a really small dataset (only 6 data points)
beer2 <- window(ausbeer,start=2006,end=2006-.1)
print(beer2)

beerfit1 <- meanf(beer2,h=11)
beerfit2 <- rwf(beer2,h=11)
beerfit3 <- snaive(beer2,h=11)

plot(beerfit1, plot.conf=FALSE, main="Forecasts for quarterly beer production")
lines(beerfit2$mean,col=2)
lines(beerfit3$mean,col=3)
lines(ausbeer)
legend("topright", lty=1, col=c(4,2,3), legend=c("Mean method","Naive method","Seasonal     naive method"))

beer3 <- window(ausbeer, start=2006)
accuracy(beerfit1, beer3)
accuracy(beerfit2, beer3)
accuracy(beerfit3, beer3)

#now make a really small daily dataset (Each day for two weeks)
forecast_datesequence = seq(from=as.Date("2013-05-06"), to=as.Date("2013-05-19"), by=1)
vals <- c(100,150,300,150,100,45,25,100,150,300,150,100,45,25)

dailyzoo_ts <- zoo(vals, forecast_datesequence)
print(daily_ts)

dailyfit1 <- meanf(coredata(dailyzoo_ts),h=7)
dailyfit2 <- rwf(coredata(dailyzoo_ts),h=7)
dailyfit3 <- snaive(coredata(dailyzoo_ts),h=7)

plot(dailyfit1, plot.conf=FALSE, main="Daily Data Over 2 Week Period")
lines(dailyfit2$mean,col=2)
lines(dailyfit3$mean,col=3)
lines(dailyzoo_ts)
legend("topright", lty=1, col=c(4,2,3), legend=c("Mean method","Naive method","Seasonal naive method"))
```

---

Here is an updated bit of R code that still does not work

```
#now make a really small daily dataset (Each day for two weeks)
forecast_datesequence = seq(from=as.Date("2013-05-06"), to=as.Date("2013-05-19"), by=1)
vals <- c(100,150,300,150,100,45,25,100,150,300,150,100,45,25)

dailyzoo_ts <- zoo(vals, forecast_datesequence)
print(daily_ts)

z <- zoo(coredata(dailyzoo_ts), 1:14/7)
print(z)
plot(forecast(z))
#stl(z)

dailyfit1 <- meanf(z,h=7)
dailyfit2 <- rwf(z,h=7)
dailyfit3 <- snaive(z,h=7)

plot(dailyfit1, plot.conf=FALSE, main="Daily Data Over 2 Week Period")
lines(dailyfit2$mean,col=2)
lines(dailyfit3$mean,col=3)
lines(z)
legend("topright", lty=1, col=c(4,2,3), legend=c("Mean method","Naive method","Seasonal naive method"))
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Provide a reproducible example of your problem. This works for me: `forecast(zoo(1:5))`

Comment: Hi 

Here is some sample code. With a simple quarterly dataset, I can get some prediction working but with a daily dataset I can't get it working.

Answer (score 1):

`forecast` requires that the period be 1 time unit so try this:

```
>     z <- zoo(coredata(dailyzoo_ts), 0:15/7)
>     plot(forecast(z))
>     meanf(z)
   Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
1         124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
2         124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
3         124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
4         124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
5         124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
6         124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
7         124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
8         124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
9         124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
10        124.375 11.38063 237.3694 -55.27649 304.0265
>     rwf(z)
         Point Forecast      Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95
16.14286            150   31.13735 268.8627  -31.78474 331.7847
16.28571            150  -18.09718 318.0972 -107.08245 407.0824
16.42857            150  -55.87615 355.8762 -164.86041 464.8604
16.57143            150  -87.72531 387.7253 -213.56948 513.5695
16.71429            150 -115.78497 415.7850 -256.48304 556.4830
16.85714            150 -141.15285 441.1529 -295.27986 595.2799
17.00000            150 -164.48102 464.4810 -330.95722 630.9572
17.14286            150 -186.19435 486.1944 -364.16489 664.1649
17.28571            150 -206.58796 506.5880 -395.35422 695.3542
17.42857            150 -225.87671 525.8767 -424.85383 724.8538
>     snaive(z)
         Point Forecast Lo 80 Hi 80 Lo 95 Hi 95
2.285714            300   300   300   300   300
2.428571            150   150   150   150   150
2.571429            100   100   100   100   100
2.714286             45    45    45    45    45
2.857143             25    25    25    25    25
3.000000            100   100   100   100   100
3.142857            150   150   150   150   150
3.285714            300   300   300   300   300
3.428571            150   150   150   150   150
3.571429            100   100   100   100   100
3.714286             45    45    45    45    45
3.857143             25    25    25    25    25
4.000000            100   100   100   100   100
4.142857            150   150   150   150   150
>     stl(z, "periodic")
 Call:
 stl(x = z, s.window = "periodic")

Components
Time Series:
Start = c(0, 1) 
End = c(2, 2) 
Frequency = 7 
           seasonal    trend     remainder
0.0000000 -24.28571 124.2857  4.263256e-14
0.1428571  25.71429 124.2857 -2.842171e-14
0.2857143 175.71429 124.2857 -1.421085e-14
0.4285714  25.71429 124.2857 -1.421085e-14
0.5714286 -24.28571 124.2857 -1.421085e-14
0.7142857 -79.28571 124.2857 -1.421085e-14
0.8571429 -99.28571 124.2857  1.421085e-14
1.0000000 -24.28571 124.2857  4.263256e-14
1.1428571  25.71429 124.2857 -1.421085e-14
1.2857143 175.71429 124.2857  0.000000e+00
1.4285714  25.71429 124.2857  0.000000e+00
1.5714286 -24.28571 124.2857  1.421085e-14
1.7142857 -79.28571 124.2857  2.842171e-14
1.8571429 -99.28571 124.2857 -1.421085e-14
2.0000000 -24.28571 124.2857 -7.105427e-14
2.1428571  25.71429 124.2857  8.526513e-14
```

Comment: forecast works but stl() does not, nor does any of the other functions in the Forecast package

Comment: `stl` requires 2 full periods so use `zz <- zoo(coredata(dailyzoo_ts), 0:13/7); stl(zz, "periodic")`.  `meanf(z)`, `rwf(z)` and `snaive(z)` all give output.  Please define precisely what it is that is not giving you what you expect.

Comment: stl() still gives an error eg series is not periodic or has less than two periods. snaive() also gives an error Error in .cbind.ts(list(e1, e2), c(deparse(substitute(e1))[1L], deparse(substitute(e2))[1L]),  : 
  not all series have the same frequency. Also the dates get lost when the returned forecast in plotted. Thanks heaps for your help.

Comment: Also what are the index values for zz after 0:13/7 is used?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  That should have been 0:15/7 rather than 0:13/7.  I have pasted the output into the answer.

Comment: Thanks - that works but I lose the date information. Is there any way I can get my datesequence incorporated eg 
forecast_datesequence = seq(from=as.Date("2013-05-06"), to=as.Date("2013-05-19"), by=1)
z2 <- zoo(coredata(dailyzoo_ts), forecast_datesequence/7)

Comment: This may vary by the specific function but stl requires that the period be one unit which is not consistent with the internals of Date class and I believe that many of the forecast functions convert to ts so dates won't be kept.

Comment: Thank you so much G. Grothendieck.

Comment: i'm still struggling to get this working for weeks. Lets say I have x <- c(0:104) which gives 104 entries for 2 years made up of 52 weeks each. To place this into a zoo objects with 52 entries for each z observation I try this z <- zoo(x, 0:104/52) but it does not work. Please help.

Comment: What does not work?  The `z` you have defined consists of the 2 numbers 0 and 104 repeated to fill out the 105 positions.